# Failed audit: Do not use answers to closed questions as tests?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, review-suspension

Today I failed a review in "low quality posts" for an answer to a closed question by voting "Looks OK" (expected: "Recommend deletion"). This is the question:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15720270*

The question is off-topic on Stack Overflow as it is asking to recommend a tool.

Some user responded with a suggestion of various tools and a link to some article which is discussing this problem in depth.

My personal thought was like this:

- You may downvote this answer as off missing explanations
- However, basically it answers the question
- It is not link-only as essential parts are inside the answer
- It does not just promote a product as many options were given
- It may be useful to future readers having the same problem

After all, I would not recommend to delete it without deleting the question. Probably most of you would have decided differently, but is this definitely certain for an answer to a question like this?

***My suggestion***: *Do not use answers to closed questions in review audits as this may be confusing*.

Usually in the low quality posts queue decisions are pretty clear. However deleting a possibly useful answer is not clear in such a way that you should use it as an audit test?

Comment: That's why you get shown the question along with the answer: in context, the answer shouldn't be deleted. The audit should help you to identify these cases and deal with the question accordingly while skipping the review. So, how to pass the audit: skip. (at least we stopped using spam in the LQRQ, or so I hope).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it was wasn't directly promoting a product, that answer was spam attempting to direct traffic to this user's LinkedIn profile and his consulting services. It was flagged as spam by multiple users and destroyed as such, along with all these posts:

[image]

I may have become paranoid after handling spam like this for years, but that wording and formatting has all the marks of self-promotional material. All the other posts spamming this link confirms it, but you don't have access to that.

True spam answers are great audits, and they catch many terrible reviewers before they can do more damage to the site. Many of them come on closed questions, so I think it would be detrimental to exclude those.

A better solution would be [to allow selective disputing of audit cases to identify and remove potentially confusing ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790). But of course I'd say that.